# A faster way to fill nan values with average

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, joblib

I had the previous question closed so reposting it with more context. I was running this command on a dataset that is relatively large (59 gb). With a shape of `(800,000, 10,500)`, I noticed that running on my aws ec2 instance `df.fillna(df.mean())` was taking extraordinarily long, after 4 hours I just cancelled the cell from running. Is there a faster way of calculating the average and filling each `nan` value of each column?

Here is a sample set of the data

```
d = {'B19325_038E': {409606: 9.0, 403811: 53.0, 400166: 17.0, 402573: 105.0, 400130: 43.0, 404907: 21.0, 406751: 15.0, 403850: 39.0, 404089: 81.0, 409843: np.nan}, 'B08302_014E': {409606: 2.0, 403811: 156.0, 400166: 64.0, 402573: 211.0, 400130: 140.0, 404907: 90.0, 406751: 148.0, 403850: 71.0, 404089: 341.0, 409843: 91.0}, 'B17010I_026E': {409606: np.nan, 403811: 9.0, 400166: np.nan, 402573: np.nan, 400130: np.nan, 404907: np.nan, 406751: np.nan, 403850: np.nan, 404089: np.nan, 409843: 21.0}, 'B17015_009E': {409606: 30.0, 403811: 18.0, 400166: 12.0, 402573: 5.0, 400130: 6.0, 404907: 11.0, 406751: 23.0, 403850: 49.0, 404089: 37.0, 409843: 60.0}, 'B06003_004E': {409606: 1552.0, 403811: 3562.0, 400166: 2536.0, 402573: 4911.0, 400130: 1913.0, 404907: 1888.0, 406751: 4264.0, 403850: 2087.0, 404089: 1443.0, 409843: 867.0}, 'B15001_038E': {409606: 46.0, 403811: 104.0, 400166: 89.0, 402573: 120.0, 400130: 61.0, 404907: 14.0, 406751: 60.0, 403850: 198.0, 404089: 97.0, 409843: 25.0}, 'B08130_006E': {409606: 280.0, 403811: 2325.0, 400166: 1381.0, 402573: 2907.0, 400130: 1300.0, 404907: 1528.0, 406751: 2502.0, 403850: 1278.0, 404089: 1986.0, 409843: 308.0}, 'B19201_002E': {409606: 80.0, 403811: 75.0, 400166: 24.0, 402573: 54.0, 400130: np.nan, 404907: np.nan, 406751: 43.0, 403850: 62.0, 404089: 32.0, 409843: 33.0}, 'B19325_087E': {409606: 35.0, 403811: 29.0, 400166: 33.0, 402573: 72.0, 400130: 20.0, 404907: np.nan, 406751: 39.0, 403850: 40.0, 404089: 40.0, 409843: 5.0}, 'B06003_008E': {409606: 106.0, 403811: 458.0, 400166: 296.0, 402573: 505.0, 400130: 277.0, 404907: 804.0, 406751: 1037.0, 403850: 726.0, 404089: 1854.0, 409843: 80.0}, 'B16006_003E': {409606: 30.0, 403811: 525.0, 400166: 160.0, 402573: 33.0, 400130: 386.0, 404907: 2.0, 406751: 55.0, 403850: 121.0, 404089: 686.0, 409843: 228.0}, 'C14007A_004E': {409606: np.nan, 403811: np.nan, 400166: np.nan, 402573: np.nan, 400130: np.nan, 404907: np.nan, 406751: np.nan, 403850: np.nan, 404089: np.nan, 409843: np.nan}, 'C14007A_005E': {409606: np.nan, 403811: np.nan, 400166: np.nan, 402573: np.nan, 400130: np.nan, 404907: np.nan, 406751: np.nan, 403850: np.nan, 404089: np.nan, 409843: np.nan}, 'C14007A_003E': {409606: np.nan, 403811: np.nan, 400166: np.nan, 402573: np.nan, 400130: np.nan, 404907: np.nan, 406751: np.nan, 403850: np.nan, 404089: np.nan, 409843: np.nan}, 'C21001I_003E': {409606: 31.0, 403811: 287.0, 400166: 86.0, 402573: 25.0, 400130: 235.0, 404907: 35.0, 406751: 32.0, 403850: 73.0, 404089: 384.0, 409843: 84.0}, 'C21001I_006E': {409606: np.nan, 403811: 35.0, 400166: np.nan, 402573: np.nan, 400130: np.nan, 404907: np.nan, 406751: 13.0, 403850: 17.0, 404089: 19.0, 409843: 6.0}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Here is a picture of my machine using `htop` to show you the status of where it is at when it is running `df.fillna(df.mean()`

[image]

As you can see it appears to be working, but I do not see the memory fluctuating at all and thus could be frozen? Hard to tell and a waste of money to let it just keep going more than 4 hours.

Is there a way of parallelizing `df.fillna(df.mean())` to make it run faster?

To provide even more context here is what I am currently trying since up until now, no one seems to know.

```
def fill_nan(df, col):
    df[col].fillna(df[col].mean(),inplace=True)
    return df

col_list=all_data.columns.tolist()
l = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(fill_nan)(df=all_data,col=cols) for cols in col_list)
```

The problem with this is I am getting this error

```
TerminatedWorkerError: A worker process managed by the executor was unexpectedly terminated. This could be caused by a segmentation fault while calling the function or by an excessive memory usage causing the Operating System to kill the worker.

The exit codes of the workers are {SIGSEGV(-11)}
```

Despite the error, would this method actually make the computation faster?

Comment: If you can manage to cut your data into smaller segments, you can then run numba to parallelize the load on your ec2. [Numba tuto](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/parallel.html)

Comment: This question is an exact duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68696788/a-more-efficient-approach-to-df-fillna-on-larger-sets-of-data-parallelizatio). Please improve the other question and request reopening.

Comment: Look into dask dataframe, if you want some code help please do improve / request reopening as @mozway said.

Comment: What is the expected result for your example? Especially, what it is when all the input values of a given column are NaN? The mean is undefined in that case resulting in a division by zero. AFAIK, in the worst case, this can cause floating-point exceptions and possibly segfaults (like the one you have) in some platforms.

Comment: @JérômeRichard The method above i.e. `df.fillna(df.mean())` will ignore the NaN and fill them with the average. I am kinda surprised you did not look that up before commenting.

Comment: I think there is a big problem not related to `df.fillna(df.mean())`. Indeed, a 10 times smaller random dataset fitting in RAM is computed sequentially in 6 second on my relatively-chip machine (quite standard with a i5-9600KF). A data frame of size `(800_000, 10_500)` not fitting in RAM and computed on my disk took 15 minutes. This is >=16 times faster the reported execution time on the EC2 instance. The expected time on my machine if I would have enough RAM is 60 second, resulting in a 240 times faster execution... Using 96 cores would be still slower than using 1 core of my machine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per experience, `.fillna()` with all columns is more expensive than applying it selectively with the columns which have `nan`. As a matter of fact, observe the results on the following two functions:

```
def fill_nan1(df):
    col_list = df.columns.tolist()
    for col in col_list:
        df[col].fillna(df[col].mean(),inplace=True)
    return df

def fill_nan2(df):
    for col in df.columns[df.isnull().any(axis=0)]:
        df[col].fillna(df[col].mean(),inplace=True)
    return df
```

`.fillna()` applied to all columns of `df` in `fill_nan1()` (how it is done in your case) while it is applied only with columns with `nan` in `fill_nan2()`. `timeit` on both resulted in the following:

```
>>%timeit fill_nan1(df)
2.35 ms ± 25 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

>>%timeit fill_nan2(df)
938 µs ± 8.06 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Also if this is for ML purpose, split your data into train and test before filling your `nan` values because that doesn't only make your computation faster but also avoid you from wrong imputation.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this version with numpy?

```
x = df.values
avg = np.nanmean(x, axis=0)
idx = np.nonzero(np.isnan(x))
x[idx] = np.take(avg, idx[1])
```

The nan values of your dataframe will be updated automatically because `x = df.values` is not a copy of your data.

Comment: Interesting, I'm looking forward to getting the feedback from OP!

Comment: Does this replace the values of the dataframe in place? How would I update the dataframe to reflect the replaced nan values in each column?

Comment: The values are updated in place. Don't worry about that.

Comment: I get a `ZeroDivisionError: division by zero` error. Also, just testing on the dataframe with 50,000 rows it appears this method is not as fast or efficient.